# How to see what files spotlight is currently indexing

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, spotlight, mds

Spotlight has been driving me nuts, over working my poor Harddrive so that my whole computer goes to a crawl. (CPU usage is still pretty low, then again I do have a core i7).

I saw somewhere that there was a way to see what it was currently indexing but I don't remember where.

**Any ideas as to see what it's indexing?**

I want to see if it's some files that keep doing it, then just put that folder in the ignore list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried

```
sudo opensnoop -p PID
```

where PID is the process ID of `mdworker`?

Comment: sudo opensnoop -n mdworker will avoid you finding the PID.

Comment: No longer works on recent versions of macOS unless you disable system integrity protection.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the fs_usage command to see the list of files visited by the mdworker process:

> sudo fs_usage -w -f filesys mdworker | egrep "open"

Hope it helps!